# Java UI White Screen after networking code executed

Tags: java, user-interface, networking

I want to implement networking features into my game, however I have a great problem. When I try to create the JFrame component, after the networking code was executed, it always comes up as a white screen. While the networking works, I couldn't get the UI working in any way. Here's the networking code:

```
package progtech2bea;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class NetworkController implements Runnable {

public Main base;
private MainMenu mm;
private String ip;
private int port = 22222;
public int pnum;

private Thread thread;
private Socket socket;
private DataOutputStream os;
private DataInputStream is;

private ServerSocket serversocket;

private int errcount = 0;
private boolean commerror;

private boolean client;
private boolean accepted = false;

public void beginServer(String ip, MainMenu mm)
{
    this.ip = ip;
    this.mm = mm;
    if (!connect()) {
        initalizeServer();
        pnum = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        pnum = 2;
    }

    thread = new Thread(this, "WaterWar");
    thread.run();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        tick();
        //m.repaint();

        if (!client && !accepted) {
            listenServerRequest();
        }
    }

}

private boolean connect() {
    try {
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        accepted = true;
        mm.dispose();
        base.showMain();
        base.moveToP2StartView();
        System.out.println("Successfully connected");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("No active server, initalizing new one");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private void initalizeServer() {
    try {
        serversocket = new ServerSocket(port, 8, InetAddress.getByName(ip));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error initalizing the server");
    }

    client = false;
}

public void listenServerRequest() {
    Socket s = null;

    try {
        s = serversocket.accept();
        os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        accepted = true;
        System.out.println("The client successfully connected");
        base.showMain();
        mm.dispose();            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}

public void tick() {

}
}
```

The jFrame works perfectly fine, if the networking code didn't ran. The following doesn't work, which gets called in a seperate class:

```
//the jFrame component initalizing all the UI elements inside
Main m = new Main(jTextField1.getText(),jComboBox1.getSelectedIndex());
//calls the NetworkController's beginServer() method, trying to establish 
//connection/start a server
nc.beginServer(jTextField2.getText(),this);
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to make the thread initalization outside of this runnable object, and then run it as:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {...});
t.start();
```